# Using cfcontent in ColdFusion 7, how do I output an MS Word doc in landscape mode?

Tags: coldfusion, ms-word, landscape

The title is pretty self explanatory. I'm using [cfcontent](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/7/htmldocs/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=ColdFusion_Documentation&file=00000232.htm) in ColdFusion 7 to output a page as an application/msword file type and I want to know how to make it default to landscape mode without resorting to downloading a third party library.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the content is just html, you could use the mso/xml schemas. There is a bit more to it than this, but the "mso-page-orientation" property should do the trick.

```
<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
    xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
 ...
 <style>
 <!--
  @page Section1
  {   size:11.0in 8.5in;
      mso-page-orientation:landscape;
      ...
  }
 -->
 </style>
```

For a good quick start, create a very simple document in MS Word. Change the orientation etcetera and save it as html. The generated html will be a bit verbose, but is pretty easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating an rtf-based document, review [this page](http://p2p.wrox.com/pro-vb-6/9018-rich-text-files-output-landscape-8-5-x-11-a.html) for some ideas:

> I don't know how helpful this is, but
>   I created a simple RTF file in
>   MS-Word, and then looked at it. I
>   found the following in some of the
>   formatting:
>
> \paperw15840\paperh12240
>
> 15840 is 1440 * 11 12240 is 1440 * 8.5

There are links to other sites including the rtf specification on that page.